# backbone view not work with this.model.toJSON()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have implemented an view on my backbone code trying show all modifications before add data on my model. but for some reason my view  returns "this.model.toJSON() is not a function" all the time i try add something from my form. i'm not undestand what's wrong.

it occours inside view "userView" render(). follow my 2 views, model and collections.

model:

```
      var userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
          defaults: function() {
            return {
              nome: '',
              sobrenome: ''
            };
          }
      });
```

view:

```
         var userView = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: new userModel(),
            tagName : 'div',
            initialize: function(){
              this.template = _.template($("#user-template").html());
            },
            render : function() {
               this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
               return this;
            }
         });
```

view 2:

```
        var userViewes = Backbone.View.extend({
            model: users,
            el: $("#user-container"),
            initialize: function(){
              this.model.on("add", this.render, this);
            },
            render: function() {
              var self = this;
              self.$el.html("");
              _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(user, i){
                self.$el.append((new userView({model:  userModel })).render().$el);
              });

              return this;
            }
         });
```

and finally, my collection :

```
        var userCollections = Backbone.Collection.extend({
          model: userModel
        });
```

sorry for any mistake.

Comment: Have you tried testing for the model first: `console.log(this.model)`?

Comment: ya. return this -> function (){ return parent.apply(this, arguments); }

Comment: That looks like an uninitialized model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is your passing an uninitialized model to the view. Instead of `userModel`, pass `user`

```
_.each(this.model.toArray(), function(user, i){
    self.$el.append((new userView({model:  user })).render().$el);
});
```

Also, you dont need to do `this.model.toArray()`, instead you can do this:

```
this.model.each(function(user, i){
    self.$el.append((new userView({model:  user })).render().$el);
});
```

> Personally I'd call my collection `collection` and not `model`

Comment: it solved the problem about "this.model.toJSON()". but the app still not showing the data on the view. in this case, the username.

Comment: Verify that the model contains the username. Also, where is your template code? (#user-template)

Comment: i have got the problem. i put the js in end of document and its all alright.